# How can I distinguish accents on INSERT but collapse them on SELECT?

Tags: mysql

I'm using PHP with mysqli to insert and retrieve data.

Using INSERT IGNORE, I want a new record when two values differ in accents.

Currently, my collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci, and if I use INSERT IGNORE with values of

```
Santa Maria
```

and

```
Santa María
```

I don't get a new record for the second one, because it's seen as identical to the first one.

I want to see all the variations, regardless of case or accents, when I do a SELECT:

```
SELECT * from places where name LIKE "%maria%";

Santa Maria
Santa María
Calle demaria
```

I've tried setting my collation for the name field to utf8mb4_bin, but then my SELECTs are case-sensitive and accent-sensitive.

What's the best way for me to distinguish accented characters on INSERT, but not on SELECT?

Can I set up multiple indexes or something, and specify the index in my mysqli PHP query?

Comment: unable to reproduce this issue [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6e2ac/2)

Comment: Thank you. Clearly there's some other problem with my code. Thanks for pointing me to that SQL Fiddler - I had seen similar tools but didn't know that existed, and you helped me take a closer look at my database. I haven't completely fixed my problem yet, but at least I'm not looking in the wrong place anymore.

Comment: Well, now that I've looked at it again: I can't insert "Maria" and "María" into the name column at all, because I've got it indexed as unique. How do I insert multiple values that vary by accents into a unique field?